# Passing values between XAML pages

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to build my first Windows 8 Metro App using VS 2012 & C#.

It consists of a simple 2 pages layout, the first being the presentation & setup page and the second consists of the game itself (a quiz).

I have created an instance of Player in the MainPage.xaml.cs that stores the Player Name, the game mode (easy, medium, hard) and the subject of the questions (eventually).

```
Player p = new Player();
```

Whenever the values are set i navigate to MainGame.xaml using

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainGame));
```

The question is: how do I pass such values between pages so I can, say, set a Textblock saying "Name is Playing"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can pass parameter object in `Frame`'s [`Navigate(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh702394) method. So you should write like this.

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
Player p = new Player();
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainGame), p);
```

Now that object of `Player` can be get in `MainGame.xaml.cs`'s `OnNavigatedTo(...)` method.

MainGame.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e) 
{ 
    var objPlayer = e.Parameter as Player; 
}
```